# Magento 2: Move pager to bottom

Tags: magento2, php, phtml

I see this code in toolbar.html

```
    <?php echo $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
```

And these in list.html

```
<?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>


    <div class="tollbar-bottom">
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
```

I want to show the pager at the bottom of the pages and keep sort by at the top

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom template based on toolbar.phtml and retrive it on the top of page in lust.phtml instead first getToolbarHtml() ?>

Comment: So pretty much a toolbar.phtml with only the pager?